# Limited Speed per Download, Have to Download Multiple Files at Once to Get Better Speed

Tags: networking, download, bandwidth

Average speed of any download in current college LAN network I get is ~500 KB/s. But I can download multiple files I want and all of them will have the same ~500 KB/s. Which looks like:
[IDM SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIZOr.png)

IDM is already using 8 connections per file, so I'm not sure what can be done to improve speed. Other than that, say YouTube streaming is ~60-100 KB/s while I can download videos at ~500 KB/s. So streaming is not a good experience as well.
The problem is not with the server since 500 KB/s is max I get anywhere.
The network might be throttling individual connections. But shouldn't having multiple connections improve the speed if downloading multiple files from same server multiplies the speed.
Anything that can be improve the situation

Edit: Increased the number of connections, and it did increase the speed. So I guess, I'll just have use very high number of connections till I can utilize the speed fully. Which would also explain why streaming sucks.

Comment: do you have an actual question?

Comment: Assuming you're using Windows. Update your network driver to the latest from the driver distributor, like Realtek or Intel. There's a known "feature" in Windows recently that severely breaks network speeds. Let me know if this is helpful in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't getting faster speeds on a per download basis by using multiple segments, it is possibly your college is using DPI techniques and/or limiting bandwidth on a per target (or source) basis rather than per individual connection.

I wouldn't work around this as you may be in breach of the terms and conditions.

If you really want to work around it, look for different mirrors you can probably use and it may work if you can split between them.

Comment: This does not require deep packet inspection - and indeed DPS won't help if the connection is HTTPS and they have not installed a cert on this computer.

Comment: @davidgo I said and/or... I also said the same as you, limiting on a per target or source basis... And, it is possible to limit speeds on HTTPS connections without Cert - again, based purely on source/destination.

Comment: I wish to distance myself from this answer as I don't believe the issue is DPI, nor that (per original question pre edit subsequent to our answers) limiting on source **or** target basis,nor  that splitting up single downloads among multiple mirrors without p2p is a viable option. I also wanted to answer the question meaningfully by addressing the techniques required to improve the situation as per the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The college network is indeed most likely throttling connections to 500kbps - and it looks like its doing it on a per source+destination pair.

Depending on how this is being implemented you MIGHT be able to get around it using a UDP based VPN(eg OpenVPN) - on the shaky assumption  that this throttling is being done by dropping TCP packets.

If thats not the case(and its probably not) , other then getting an alternative connection which bypassed the college network, your best option would be to approach the administrators and see if you can pay for better access - to do otherwise could be a breach of your agreement, and regardless, is likely to compound the tragedy of the commons issue you are already causing.

You risk getting into trouble for hacking, and its an all round bad idea and difficult to implement, but, theoretically speaking, it is likely you could get additional IP addresses and use some complex tricks to load balance streams between IP addresses - with or without using a VPN to another point.  Doing this is particularly tricky and most likely requires additional hardware - the specifics of doing this are also dependent on your network setup.

The most logical way to fix the problem would be to use software to download Youtube videos prior to you watching them.  I hesitate to advise this, but it may also be practical to get data using P2P software, which opens connections to multiple IP addresses and will most likely be immune to the limitation you are trying to bypass - although there may well be other limitations (like a shared low-bandwidth pool for all P2P)

Answer (score 0):

You are being a bandwidth piggy. 
The reason for policies like this is so other people on the college LAN can access resources.

You will be robbing other students who have actual homework to do, and probably blocking them from the LAN resources they require.

Circumventing administrator policies can be a big deal in some schools. It's not worth it, if you absolutely need more bandwidth.... Pay for it.
Or if it's for a school project, reach out to the schools IT team, they may be able to accommodate.